# How to split an image by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

In slideshows using libraries such as jQuery/jQueryUI, it is common to split a slide and disperse the fragments for disappearing the current slide. I am curious about the trick to do this with Javascript. I mean pure JS to understand the process, not implementing with an available library.

As I searched over the internet, a common way to split a image by Javascript is to set the image as a background and show fragments by CSS, but I doubt this is the method used for creating slideshow effects.

How Javascript can split an image/slide?

Comment: Showing only part of an image using CSS is called "[spriting](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)" and is quite common (and in many cases, a superior approach). This would be perfectly acceptable for a slideshow library. The only shortcoming is that the splitting is only visual -- a user could not save-to-file a particular partial image (to do that, you'll need to use a canvas).

Comment: @apsillers it is quite common to reduce the number of images (e.g. collection of icons), but not for making animation and slideshow effects (I am not sure of course, the former application is widely quoted).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `canvas` tag in HTML 5. You can import an image on the canvas and work your magic on it from there. I do not have an example in hand but you could give it a try yourself.

Comment: I am a big fan of `canvas`, and I can put your idea in action; but this should not be the trick used by slideshow JS libraries.

Comment: @All You already stated that you didn't want to use CSS and it's transformations. Obviously we can't go back to using Adobe Flash. So then I guess `canvas` is the only candidate left. Though I'd love to know if there are alternatives that I am yet unaware of.

Comment: +1: Canvas and CSS are the only Web client-side methods for splitting an image, barring browser plugins.